# Angular UI Modal controller is not exposed to directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I need to create a directive that can be used inside Angular UI modal. This directive also need to know about modal's controller in order to use some functions from it. What I have now:

**JS:**

```
'use strict';

var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', [ 'ui.bootstrap' ]);

DemoApp.controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal){
  $scope.openModal = function(){
    var scope = $scope.$new(true);

    $modal.open({
      'templateUrl' : 'modal.html',
      'controller' : 'ModalController',
      'scope' : scope
    });
  }
}]);

DemoApp.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance){
  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
  };
}]);

DemoApp.directive('expression', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    require : ['ngModel', '^ModalController'],
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
      console.log(arguments);
    }
  };
});
```

**Modal template:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3>Test!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <input data-ng-model="someValue" expression>{{someValue}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Ok</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**And the red button:**

```
<button id="demoButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="openModal()">Click me!</button>
```

But when the modal is created `ModalController` is not resolved, and I get `$compile:ctreq` error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$compile/ctreq?p0=ModalController&p1=expression
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:6:450
    at D (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:51:80)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:51:137
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:7:280)
    at D (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:51:114)
    at N (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:54:128)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:47:82)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js:47:99) <input data-ng-model="someValue" expression="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

I tried to debug the code: `getControllers()` somewhere around 6433 LOC at `angular.js` is used to search controller: `value = value || $element[retrievalMethod]('$' + require + 'Controller');`, so I tried to require `Modal` instead of `ModalController` (`Controller` is appended by Angular), but it didn't help. I cannot understand how `$element[retrievalMethod]` works (stepped into it, but it is to low-level). So, I'm stuck and appreciate any help.

I've created a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/Q4YUz3l9so6vTjmRNc7a), so you can play and see in console what I mean.

Comment: The directive will have access to the functions on the ModalController's $scope via the scope passed to the link function. Or is this for some other use case I'm missing?

Comment: Also, `require` takes the name of a directive whose controller you want to access, so specifying the controller name wouldn't work. Just use `scope`, as tasselKATT suggests.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I definitely missed that from docs, thank your for pointing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, checkout updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u4ba27dQ3xP48E7lmAE8?p=preview):

1. `ModalController` scope isn't child scope of `PageController`, so if you need to pass variables to `ModalController` you should do it through resolving dependencies directly.
2. In your directive you can set scope as child of `ModalController` scope, so you can have access to functions defined there instead of requiring `ModalController`.

Comment: Wow, so simple! I've overcomplicated my task! Thank you.